# How to prevent jump before scroll animation from jquery validate invalid handler?

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery validate plugin to validate my forms. If the form is invalid I want to scroll back to the top of the page.

Currently the page flashes and then scrolls up as expected. I need to remove this flash which appears to be jumping to the top of the page. I believe it is because the default button behaviour is not being prevented.

Normally when trying to prevent default actions elsewhere, I would return false, or preventDefault on the event object. This doesn't seem to be working here because the event target is the form not the button being clicked.

From the docs the invalid handler passes event and validator objects. My below code still flashes even though false is returned.

```
invalidHandler: function(event, validator){

    $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: 0
    }, 1000);

    return false;

}
```

The form is submitted from a submit button:

```
<button type ="submit" class="btn green ladda-button" data-style="zoom-out">
    <span class="ladda-label">Save Changes</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by ensuring that the focusInvalid property was set to false.

```
focusInvalid: false,
invalidHandler: function(event, validator){

    $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: 0
    }, 1000);

    return false;
}
```

By default jQuery Validate moves focus to the first invalid field.